# How to whitelist editing on certain pages in Mediawiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki, editing, whitelist

So I have a Mediawiki server running on my raspberryPi and I have it set so that nothing can be read without logging in except the main page and a page called Public.

I'd like this Public page to not only be readable by unlisted users, but also editable by unlisted users (Unlike the rest of the wiki where you have to sign in). Like a guestbook kind of thing.

I have the read restriction in LocalSettings.php set up like this:

```
//Disable reading by anon users
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
//Page Whitelist
$wgWhitelistRead = array ("Main_Page", "PUBLIC");
```

This definitely works for restricting/allowing reading, but there doesn't seem to be a WhitelistEdit variable or any other variable for whitelisting editing, nor have I found a stable extension for MW that allows this.

So I guess what I'm asking is: Does anyone know of a way to whitelist unlisted editing and reading on a single page Mediawiki? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki does not support intricate access rules by default. Extensions might exist that do this although I am not aware of any. It's probably pretty simple to write one with the [userCan](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/userCan) hook, though (or you can just put the hook directly in your config file).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only thing I can think of is to enable editing for everyone (including anonymous users) and semi-protect every page except that one.